# Why is all of my code blocks adding horizontal scroll bars?

Tags: wordpress

I must say that I don't know CSS but I am willing to learn if that's what it takes but I don't know where to start.

Some information and I am running the default Wordpress theme twentytwenty..

All of my code blocks are adding horizontal scrollbars which I don't want, I just want the code to not have any scroll bars.

Is there anyone that could help me remove them

The post in question is here and they are visible all throughout the page

https://embeddedsam.blog/2020/05/02/getting-started-with-modustoolbox-and-visual-studio-code/

Best wishes

Sam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to go into the WP Customizer for the default TwentyTwenty Theme and look for the **Additional CSS** panel at the bottom of the customizer.  Then add the following:

```
.wp-block-code{
     white-space: break-spaces;
}
```

That essentially tells the code block to break to a new line when it hits the end of the container's constraints, it then looks for the closest 'space' before whatever word is hitting the edge and starts a new line at that space.

Comment: Thankyou so much for helping and this has got rid of the scroll bars but now all of the code has become jumbled... do you know what might have caused this?.. it is live currently on the link above

Comment: I figured out the issue, I was copying directly from a terminal which didn't have any of the line breaks added to it. As soon as I am copying from Visual Studio Code then it is adding the line breaks and it is working fine. Thankyou